# report builder 2.0 count function

Tags: report, builder

I am trying to customize a report for **stock status** in our warehouse.
The current report does not total the number of pallets so I added a spot to count the number of movable units.

The problem is once an order is shipped out the line item still stays on the report but the **qty available** of pieces goes blank since nothing is there.

So I want to make it that I can Count the **qty available** if it is **greater than 0** and I want to count 1 if it is **less than 1** but I don't want it to count anything.

I have tried all sorts of combinations and can't get it right.

I think if I understand right that i need to do something like

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!SUMOFONHAND.Value>0)=1.(IIF(Fields!SUMOFONHAND.Value<1)=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIF works like this: IIF(expression, true, false)

So you want this:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!SUMOFONHAND.Value > 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: I tried and it still seems to count everything even things with no value.

Comment: Sorry you want SUM not COUNT. You can't to sum the values so that 0s are ignored

Comment: No problem, mark my answer as the answer if that's it :)